# User Defined Column in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Is it possible in odoo8 to add or remove columns in a list/tree by a user/frontend User?

Comment: Please clear your question. You want to just hide or permanently remove field from the table .?

Comment: Can you please share why you require this functionality ?

Comment: I just want the end user to defined or adjust the reports based on what they want to see in the reports, for example I've created a view with 10 Columns that show the employment History of an Employees now the user can select a columns for what he wants to see in the said reports. Its like I as a developer will produce all data/columns in a selected records in the database and the User will just create his own reports.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to add a new field to odoo view through web interface and avoid it to be removed while updating modules ([reference](https://www.agilebg.com/blog/blog-1/post/how-to-add-a-new-field-to-odoo-view-through-web-interface-1))

1. Activate developer mode
2. Go to Configuration -> technical -> Database structure -> Models
3. Open for example account.invoice
4. Add a textual field x_test
5. Go to invoices list
6. From debug menu click on manage views
7. Click on edit
8. Click on the field where you want to add the new field (e.g. state)
9. Click on inherited view
10. Select the new node (state) and click on '+'
11. Select x_test
12. Update
13. Close